# IE 9 tr border not working

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

How to give border for tr in IE 9 currently, I used below code for do that, But it doesn't work for IE 9

```
display: table;  
border: 1px solid silver; 
padding: 5px; 
margin-bottom: 5px; 
width: 980px;
```

Comment: why would you use `display:table` for a `tr` element???

Comment: without that border not visible

Comment: let me put it another way: if you're doing `display:table` on a `tr`, then you're doing something very badly wrong. You haven't given us enough code for me to give you any meaningful advice on how to fix it, but I can say it's not a surprise to hear that it isn't working in all browsers.

Comment: display:table...??for tr??:S

Comment: Did you look at this in the developer tools? Does it show that the element should have a border?

Comment: @ChelzAdams You comment, "without that border not visible". Right, but you complain that the border is not visible with `display:table` either! Now doesn't that give you a clue that you may need to find another way?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `{display:table}` on tr.

If you want, you can use `outline`, like this:

```
tr {outline:1px solid silver}
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/prgpy/2/)

Edit: one reason that `display:table` on a tr is bad, is that it messes up the table layout itself. In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/9zH5c/) you can see that the second table, with the faulty style, is malformed. (On browsers that support `display:table` on a tr at all, that is.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ie does not support css on tr
you can make this using this code

CSS

```
table td
{
        border-top: 1px solid silver;
}
table
{
        border-collapse:collapse;
        border: 1px solid silver;
}
```

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Did you mean "IE does not support ___all___ css on tr"? It certainly supports several CSS features.

Comment: is does not support border on tr